# Iterate on a Flow Loop Element in an apex collection

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have an apex class that returns a list of a custom class with the following shape

```
global without sharing class Result {
    @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
    global Id recordId;
    @AuraEnabled @InvocableVariable
    global List<Rule__c> rules;
}
```

The method returning has this shape:

```
@InvocableMethod
global static List<List<Result>> runRecords(List<Input> input) {
    ...stuff...
}
```

In the flow that consumes this method, I first iterate (without a problem) over the List of `Result` records. However, inside of each iteration I wish to iterate over the `rules` property.

I create a variable to hold the collection (so I can iterate)

[image]

However, when I want to assign the property into my collection I run into problems

[image]

If I click the caret next Result, no compatible properties appear, even though the `List<Rule__c> rules` in apex and the variable I created above are (supposedly) of the same type. Changing the operation to "Equals" does not solve the problem either.

PS: FWIW, I am in a scratch org with a namespace set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a weird chance and decided to override the GUI and deploy the change via metadata (see below)

[image]

Incredibly, the save worked and the flow now works properly. However, the GUI still does not like the change (so I cannot edit that node manually at all). This is bizarre, but it works